# I want to design this type of image slider with jetpack compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-material3

[please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9zzx.png)

I want image slider as like as in image in jetpack compose Android kotlin. I am trying in many way but now working exact same things. There are any way to do in jetpack compose is it. need a help anyone is there to do the same things